# Azure AppInsight not working for static file application

Tags: azure, iis, azure-application-insights

## Background

I have an Azure 'App Service' resource and a linked 'Application Insights' resource. They're linked via the App Service's `Settings -> Applications settings -> Application settings (key-value table)` where I have the following settings:

- `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = <my application insights instrumentation key>`
- `APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED = true`

My application is a static file application at the root `/ (site\wwwroot)` but also has 2 Asp.NET applications at 2 different virtual directories:

- `/app1 (site\app1)`
- `/app2 (site\app2)`

## Problem

The overview page shows data for something called 'Metrics' with requests, data, etc. (first image) however when I attempt to access Application Insights, no data appears (second image).

[image]

[image]

## Attemps

I've tried to follow these two guides for activating app insight for static page applications:

- http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/02/tracking-static-content-with-application-insights-httpmodule/
- http://blog.tylerdoerksen.ca/posts/2018/03/AppInsights-Static-Content

However I get an error due to the misisng DLLs in the root Bin folder.
I tried variations of:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> <!-- With and without 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests'. -->

        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"
            type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" 
            preCondition="managedHandler" /> <!-- With and without 'preCondition="managedHandler"'. -->

        <!-- And -->

        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
            type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
            preCondition="managedHandler"/> <!-- With and without 'preCondition="managedHandler"'. -->

    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

According to the second article, these missing DLLs should be automatically loaded by Azure once it knows that it's connected to AppInsight.

> If you are using Azure Web Apps. [Add the Applications Insights Extension to the Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now). This will add the proper DLLs to the Bin directory of your site.

I tried to follow the instructions under 'Monitor a live Azure web app' but the documentation seems incomplete.

## Questions

1. Why is data showing in the overview of the App Service but not AppInsight?
2. Is it possible to view website telemetry in AppInsight for my static file application at root `/`?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Why is data showing in the overview of the App Service but not AppInsight?

It should be a configure issue. You can configure it as below:

step 1:
In visual studio, right click your project name, and in the context menu, select "Configure Application Insights".

[image]

step 2:
In the following screen, click "Get started".
[image]

step 3:
In the following screen, configure your own settings(for Resource, you can create a new or use an existing one).
Then click "Register", and wait for it completes.
[image]

step 4:
If some error occurs, just fix it by tips on the screen. like below:
[image]

When you have done the above steps, you should see data in App insight(it may take a few minutes for data to display).

> 2.Is it possible to view website telemetry in AppInsight for my static file application at root /?

Yes, you can view website telemetry in AppInsight for static file application at root /.

step 1:
In the Web.config, find the `<system.webServer>` node, and then in the `<modules>` node, add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`, like below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

step 2:
Publish web site to azure.

step 3:
Launch the website to the static file, here I used test4.html for example.
[image]

step 4:
Go to azure portal -> your application sights -> Overview section, select a chart like "Server requests"(if no data, please wait for a while).
[image]

step 5:
You can see such request "GET /test4.html".
[image]